# overriding a session-scoped Managed Bean with a subclass

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-1.2, managed-bean, subclassing

In a JSF 1.2 application, can I override a session-scoped Managed Bean returned with a subclass?

**Class structure**

I have a session-scoped Managed Bean, `MainViewMB`, and its subclass, `RestrictedViewMB`:

[image: UML: <<ManagedBean>> MainViewMB extended by RestrictedViewMB]

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>mainViewMB</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.example.MainViewMB</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**Problem statement**

The EL expression `#{mainViewMB}` returns an instance of `MainViewMB`.

I would like to rebind the name `#{mainViewMB}` with an instance of `RestrictedViewMB`, so that the EL expression `#{mainViewMB}` returns an instance of the subclass for the rest of the session.

Is there a way to accomplish my goal?

**Motivating example**

`MainViewMB` handles the GUI logic behind the application's main page. When a user enters the application from a special-purpose login page, I need to provide a restricted, simplified view of the main page. Overriding some of `MainViewMB`'s properties in a subclass seems the obvious solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it manually at the moment you can/need to do it.

```
externalContext.getSessionMap().put("mainViewMB", new RestrictedViewMB());
```

This puts a new instance of `RestrictedViewMB` in the session scope with the name `mainViewMB`, effectively making it a session scoped managed bean.

You only need to take into account that managed properties and `@PostConstruct`/`@PreDestroy` are not invoked this way, you'd also have to do it manually.

Comment: Will `#{mainViewMB}` work? Is any other action required to make it work with EL?

Comment: Yes, otherwise this answer was pointless. Nope, it completely overrides any existing session attribtues, including JSF managed beans. Do you by the way understand how JSF creates and manages beans? JSF puts session scoped managed beans exactly the same way in the session map with the managed bean name as key. You're here just repeating JSF's job, but then with a different instance.

Comment: Yes and no. I understand how EJB dependency injection works, and I understand JSP/Servlet web application scopes, but my understanding of JSF has a few gaps.